# How to detect two-finger tap using Corona SDK?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I detect when a tap is done with two fingers? The tap event can tell the number of taps, but not how many touches were involved in the event. Is there any way to figure it out? I have multitouch enabled in my Corona App. I have an application that simulates a left-button mouse click on a single-finger tap. And, a right-button mouse click on a double-finger tap.

**EDIT**:

To summarize and hopefully clarify, I want to:

1. Tap with my index finger once to emulate a left-button mouse click on my app. That is, 1 touch, 1 tap.
2. Tap with both my index and middle finger at the same time once to emulate a right-button mouse click on my app. That is, 2 touches at the same time, 1 tap.

Here's what Corona Staff had to say to my question in their forums:
http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/35037-how-to-detect-two-finger-tap-in-corona

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function object:tap( event )
    if (event.numTaps >= 2 ) then
      print( "The object was double-tapped." )
    end
end
object:addEventListener( "tap" )
```

For more details regarding objects/screen taps in corona, [see this...](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/07/24/detecting-object-and-screen-taps/)

Keep coding............ :)

Comment: Thanks, but that unfortunately just tells you there were 2 taps, i.e. one right after the other. What I'm after is knowing that there was technically 1 tap with 2 fingers. I say technically because if you tap with two fingers at the same time, the event.time for each one of the two events is going to be very close but not identical. Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough, I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brent Sorrentino from Corona said: you should use multitouch.

First take a look at this http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/id.html
You can already do it by yourself.
Here is my implementation:

```lua
system.activate( "multitouch" )

local object = display.newImage( "ball.png" )
object.numTouches = 0

function object:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( self, event.id )

        self.numTouches = self.numTouches + 1

    elseif event.phase == "cancelled" or event.phase == "ended" then
        if self.numTouches <= 1 then
            print( "This is a Left click" )
            --call your onLeftClickFunction here
        end

        if self.numTouches == 2 then

            print( "This is a Right click" )
            --call your onRightClickFunction here
        end
        self.numTouches = 0
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
    end
    return true
end
object:addEventListener( "touch", object )
```